# How to setup jQuery code completion with PyCharm and Django?

Tags: jquery, pycharm, code-completion

I love code completion and I want it to work everywhere.
I tried to enable and disable JSHist and JSLint, to use explicit path to static libraries (without `{{ STATIC_URL }}`), enable and disable jQuery libraries in configuration, add the files that I use. But there is no effect.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @johnny I'm not web developer anymore. All I can say now is to store Python and JS code in separate files and fight for code completion :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to open File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries, tap Downloads, install "jquery"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTiqa.png)